# Grails geolocation plugin

Tags: grails, plugins, geolocation

I use Grails 2.0.0 in NetBeans with the Geolocation support plugin version 0.4
using this plugin, I can display the map with my position marker, but I get an exception when I try to calculate the distance between two positions:

> No such property: GeoUtils for class: org.grails.plugin.geolocation.GeolocationService

This is a piece of my code:

```
    Coordinates f = new Coordinates()
        f.setAltitude(31.634227951365595)
        f.setLongitude(-8.00504207611084)

    Coordinates t = new Coordinates()
        t.setAltitude(31.63271158235246)
        t.setLongitude(-7.999967336654663)

    GeoPosition positionFrom = new GeoPosition()
        positionFrom.setCoords(coordinatesFrom)

    GeoPosition p = new GeoPosition()
        p.setCoords(coordinatesTo)

    GeolocationService g = new GeolocationService()
        double test = g.distance(positionFrom, positionTo)
```

The probleme is in grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/geolocation/GeolocationService.groovy:

```
double distance(GeoPosition positionFrom, GeoPosition positionTo) {
    LatLngTool.distance(**GeoUtils**.convertGeopositionToLatLng(positionFrom), GeoUtils.convertGeopositionToLatLng(positionTo), getLengthUnit())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The geolocation plugin is broken. Till the author fixes it, you may want to fork it yourself and fix it for your application 
In `GeolocationService.groovy` import the `GeoUtils` class

```
import org.grails.plugin.geolocation.utils.GeoUtils
```

Then in `BuildConfig.groovy`, refer to this modified version instead,

```
grails.plugin.location.geolocation = "<local_path_to>/geolocation"
```

afaik, that should be enough to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Thinks Mr Aldrin for the response, really there is a lot of errors in the source code of this plugin I emailed the developer but he didn't answer me. but I could solve all of thos problemes and i can now use it.
If there is someone who needs help at this level, I can send to him the corrected version .. haj.abdel( at ) gmail